# Correct return value when multiple possibilities

Tags: php, coding-style

If you had a function in a class such as:

```
public function insertItemToTable($item){
   $sql = query("insert to table {$item}");
   $insertId = sql_inserted_id();
}
```

Which item would you return?

1. Would you return `true`/`false` for the function and set a class variable to the inserted id (e.g. `$this->insertedItem = sql_insert_id()`)
2. Return the value of the inserted id

Comment: This is fairly subjective. I'd return the ID from the function or false if it fails.

Comment: Returning a last ID/false is not just subjective but also pretty convenient. First of all `$obj->insertItemToTable($item)` gives you all the necessary information: ID if you need it or status of your query so you can always use it directly in comparison like `(if ($obj->insertItemToTable($item)) ) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you can do both.

```
<?php
public function insertItemToTable($item){
   if ($sql = query("insert to table {$item}")) {
       return sql_inserted_id();
   }
   return false;
}
```

It's easy to test for it in your code:

```
<?php
if (false !== ($id = $obj->insertItemToTable($item)) {
    // it was inserted, $id is the new id
} else {
    // it failed and returned false
}
```

It's a common pattern that people use, e.g.

```
<?php
if ($r = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable')) {
    while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
        //....
    }
}
```

Ultimately, it's a preference thing, and no one right way to do it.